# Is it possible to have Tkinter recognize ANSI escape characters?

Tags: python, tkinter, ansi-escape

I am trying to print a message in a `tk.Text` box. The message is the result of a function that returns a search result. I want the message to be formatted in a way where only the header is bold, and the results are normal text:

```
search_results.append(self.text.BOLD + "Top Tracks for " + artist_found + ":" + self.text.END)
for track in top_tracks['tracks']:
    search_results.append("\t- " + track['name'])
self.search_results_msg = "\n".join(search_results)
```

Where `self.text` is an instance of the class below

```
class Text_Options():
  BOLD = '\033[1m'
  END = '\033[0m'
```

Tkinter doesn't recognize the ANSI escape characters. Is there anything I could do for ANSI to work? Or what else could I do to achieve what I want. I know there is `tk.Font` but since I only want to bold the header and leave the rest of the message normal, I don't know if `.Font` will help me.

Comment: I don't know of any library that emulates console ANSI escape sequences in a Tkinter `Text` widget. However, since it sounds like the formatting you want is relatively simple. You can probably do it yourself by formatting the line(s) in the output using "tags' each of which can be associated with specific regions of text within the `Text` widget. You would then need to parse the output and determine which lines you wanted in a different color and then insert tsag around them to control the appearance of the text in them. It's somewhat like manually embedding escape sequences in the text.

Comment: For clarification, do you want to handle *all* ansi escape sequences, or are you only needing to support this one specific sequence?

Comment: Just found a module called [vtk100_colors](https://github.com/bekar/vtk100_colors) that looks promising as does [Capture colored console output in a tkinter window](https://technogems.blogspot.com/2012/01/capture-colored-console-output-in.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box. [ANSI color control](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/ANSI+color+control) has an example Tcl code to convert them to Tcl markup (basically, replace upon insertion).