# Tkinter turning unicode text into a garbled mess?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to python and `tkinter`. As just a fun side project I wanted to build a lil control panel for my Raspberry Pi. I got the ssh side of things
down I think (I'm using the `paramiko` library). I started to work on a GUI. As a starting point I wanted to use `tkinter`. For testing I made it display the output of `neofetch`. But it turns it into a garbled mess of characters. When just printing the ssh output to the console it works fine.

How it should look:

[image: How it should look]

How it looks:

[image: How it looks]

- my test code for the gui:

```py
import tkinter 
from Rasp_SSH_V1 import neofetch

neofetch window = tkinter.Tk()
window.configure(bg='grey')

neofetchlabel = tkinter.Label(text = neofetch()) 
neofetchlabel.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

- my test code for the ssh part:

```py
import paramiko
import time
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('192.168.178.32',22,'pi','REDACTED')

def neofetch():
    lines = list()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('neofetch')
    time.sleep(3)
    for line in stdout:
        lines.append(line)
    final = '\n'.join(lines)
    return(final)
```

(I don't know if it matters, but I have them in two separate scripts)

Comment: Try printing `neofetch()`. What do you get? Is it something useful?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359056/is-it-possible-to-have-tkinter-recognize-ansi-escape-characters or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696415/how-to-put-a-string-fith-first-r-characters-bold-in-listbox-tkinter

Comment: printing neofetch() works just fine :). The Ouptut is exactly how it should be.

Comment: That doesn't look like a problem with unicode, it looks  like it's printing [ansi escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359056/is-it-possible-to-have-tkinter-recognize-ansi-escape-characters)